# Add 'minutes' to a text (in date time format) and convert it back to original varchar format SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a value stored as `Varchar(50)` as "2016-07-21 16:35:05". I want to add 5 minutes to it. How do I do it? Expected output "2016-07-21 16:40:05" as a `Varchar`.

I've so far tried converting the value to `DATETIME` and adding 5 minutes. But when I try to convert it back to `varchar`, it doesn't show up in the same format.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, CAST([PickTime] AS DATETIME)) AS VARCHAR(50))
FROM 
    rawdata
```

- Output I get: Jul 21 2016  4:40PM
- But I wanted: 2016-07-21 16:40:05

Could anyone guide me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, cast([PickTime] as datetime)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
FROM rawdata
```

Comment: **Note:** the `FORMAT` function is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** and thus not available to users of earlier versions of SQL Server